# How to parse JSON dict and append the second nested portion to a list?

Tags: json, python-3.x, for-loop

The function below parses through an nested dictionary that is returned from an API call. (`message_list` is the call itself being passed in, `complete_html` is the list I am building) There are `partId` segments in the pass in that contain either `a)` the original text or `b)` HTML text. I want to call the `HTML` part, the second part, which is nested as `{'partId': '1',`

I think there is some very simple *syntax, bracket* or something of that sort in the function that needs to be added so that when attempting to append the nested `partId: 1` messages to `part_list`, I grab all of the messages. Hoping that makes sense. What am I missing?

*Please note I think that if I simply append `'mimeType': 'text/html',` instead of appending the `partId` segments first, I am unable to loop through and append **all** of the passed in messages because `partId` needs to be appended first, before doing that.*

```
[{'partId': '0', 'mimeType': 'text/plain', 'filename': '', 'headers': [{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'}, {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value': 
[{'partId': '0', 'mimeType': 'text/plain', 'filename': '', 'headers': [{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'}, {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value':



{'partId': '1', 'mimeType': 'text/html', 'filename': '', 'headers': [{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}, {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value': 
{'partId': '1', 'mimeType': 'text/html', 'filename': '', 'headers': [{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}, {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value':
```

```
def return_complete_html(message_list, complete_list):
    for msg_ in message_list:
        msg_id = msg_['id']
        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg_id, format='full').execute()
        payload = msg['payload']['parts']

        part_list = []
        
        for part_html in payload:
            
            # mimeType = part_html.get("mimeType")
            # if mimeType == "text/html":
            #     part_list.append(part_html)
            
            part_ID = part_html.get("partId")
            part_list.append(part_html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, try this to get to the second nest:

```
part_id = part.get("partId")
            if part_id == "1":
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).